# E-R diagram exercise referencing to attribute of another entity

Tags: relational-algebra

I have this E-R diagram

[image]

Now im asked to add a entity named as "kiosk".At a kiosk up to 2 items of expedition of  different category  can be expedited.How do I add this in the E-R diagram?

The category is a attribute of a item of expedition (top left corner) so how do you reference to a attribute of another entity of the same E-R model?Thanks.